# Mesh is in some sort of grid/wireframe, no idea what's happened

Tags: modeling, mesh

A while ago I suffered the consequences of hit-every-key-you-see syndrome and something happened to the mesh. Gave up a while later and now that I'm back I can't figure out how to get out of this grid mode or whatever it is.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you just changed the view option to wire-frame while in edit mode. Just look at the bottom menu bar and change it with the wire-mesh looking circle icon.

Comment: From What I can see: you are in editmode and you have the entire mesh selected --> you should see the "grid", your viewport shading is also on wireframe --> you should see the "grid". The mesh is yellow because it  is selected, deselect by pressing "a"

Comment: This is hugely subdivided mesh in Edit mode with nearly all vertices selected except for border loops in the laft and right. What do you want to get rid of ?

Comment: What do you want your cylinder to look like? as your question is written I dont know what your problem is. Please edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different shading options for your 3d view. You can change them by pressing the button beside the edit mode/ object mode selector.

[Documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/shading.html)

[image]

Comment: yep i've tried that, doesn't change it.

Comment: you dont mean editmode? Press Tab?

Comment: im in edit mode, yes.